# Engineering notations in android

Tags: java, android

How can we use engineering notations like 'ohm' or 'alpha' etc in android applications? Actually I want to have a spinner which contains ohm, megaohm, but I am unable to get the required symbols for it.

Comment: Just write the required symbol in code? Ω

Comment: what are these codes '\u2126'?

Comment: @NikeshPatel It's java encoding for Ohm.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as text as,

```
"\u2126"
```